# Problem uploading the code into an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors

I was trying to upload code for a blinking LED. It is a new Arduino Uno board. Any further help will be appreciated.I got the following error:

> Info.: OS- Ubuntu 16.04
>
> Software: Arduino IDE 1.8.5

I could not see any port.

I have tried dialout. But still it is not working.

I also have a confusion, i.e. the `Programmer` menu shows AVRISP mkll.

[image]

If anyone wants any information, please do comment.

Error:

> An error occurred while uploading the sketch
> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "COM1": No such file or directory`

Comment: An Arduino Uno on Ubuntu will typically be at /dev/ttyACM0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu and other Linux operating systems don’t name the serial ports “COM1” or similar.

They use special files like

```
/dev/tty.[something]
```

The [something] depends on the USB device driver. The IDE should list available serial ports in the Port selection menu.

Comment: there is not port available

Comment: What ports show up?

Comment: NO port is shown.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty are you in dialout group? Or better, have you read any tutorial about Arduino in Linux?

Comment: Perhaps you don’t have the right permissions to access the serial ports. Your user must have access to the serial ports. On Ubuntu, this can be accomplished by adding your user to the dialout group. Also, make sure you have the Uno plugged into the computer.

Comment: How to do it? Please elaborate.

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: I have tried it is not working.

Comment: After adding your user to the dialout group, you have to log out completely and log back in.

Comment: Stil it is not working

Comment: One troubleshooting step - unplug the board, then open a terminal window and run the `lsusb` command.  Note the devices that appear in the list.  Then plug the board back in and run `lsusb` again - you should see the new device.  If you don't, that could explain why you're not getting a list of available ports.  On my Ubuntu system (Studio, 16.04), the device name shows up as "1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter" and connects through `/dev/ttyUSB0`.